# File Permissions on Docker Container

Tags: django, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I am facing a very weird issue when uploading files to my application directory using web forms.

While everything in terms of backend seems to work very well, when files of certain extensions are uploaded (e.g. `.apk` ) the permissions are set so that **only** `root` has read access to those files, while when other types of files (e.g. images ) are normally accessible. I do not know if the extensions or the big size ( around 15 MB comparing to KBs ) but it looks like there is some kind of filtering going on, on the background

### Update

Some more information about the environment

- `nginx` container used to proxy to the django server( `gunicorn` )
- Deployment OS is `Ubuntu 16.04`
- The web app is a Django 2.2 project
- The issue seems to be related to the file size and not to the extension at all
- Seems to be related with Django moving the file from the `/tmp` directory to the `/media` directory after the upload has been completed

Comment: You have provided no information about what software you're using. Which operating system? Which web server? Which web application? What happens if you upload a 15MB file *without* a `.apk` extension?

Comment: Django handles uploads differently according to file size. Above 2.5mb it will be written to a tmp file. If you docker user is root and not a dedicated docker user, that would explain the behavior: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/file-uploads/#where-uploaded-data-is-stored But @larsks is right. We need more info to help you with your question.

Comment: I really apologize for the lack of information in my post. I really thought this was a no code problem that's why I did not want to get my question full of not needed information. Although I think the issue is what @jsbeckr mentions as I am running docker-compose as root. I will be adding more information to my post though

Comment: Please see [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I was able to find a workaround with the precious help of **@jsbeckr**.

Through [this link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS) I found out about some handy configuration to use as I could not change the user on which `docker-compose` runs on top of

```
# For files
FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS = 0o644 #or whatever fits to your needs
# For directories
FILE_UPLOAD_DIRECTORY_PERMISSIONS = 0o644
# If you need to switch it from /temp
FILE_UPLOAD_TEMP_DIR = /path/to/dir
```